# Avoid filesort when having ORDER BY column in result

Tags: mysql, join, query-performance

For a medical calendar, I've got the following query:

```
SELECT
   `events`.`StartDate`,
   `events`.`ID`,
   `events`.`EndDate`,
   `events`.`Title`,
   `insurances`.`Title`,
   `personsPatients`.`PrimaryPhone`,
   `personsDocs`.`Name`

FROM `events`

LEFT JOIN `events++persons` ON `events`.`ID` = `events++persons`.`FirstEntityID` AND `events++persons`.`Type` = 'Patient'
LEFT JOIN `persons` AS `personsPatients` ON `events++persons`.`SecondEntityID` = `personsPatients`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN `insurances` ON `persons`.`Provider` = `insurances`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN `events++persons` AS `events++persons1` ON `events`.`ID` = `events++persons1`.`FirstEntityID` AND `events++persons1`.`Type` = 'Doctor'
LEFT JOIN `persons` AS `personsDoctors` ON `events++persons`.`SecondEntityID` = `personsDoctors`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN `companies++events` ON `events`.`ID` = `companies++events`.`SecondEntityID` 

WHERE
   ((`events`.`Type` = 'Annotation' and `companies++events`.`FirstEntityID` IS NULL) or 
    (`events`.`Type` = 'Annotation' and `companies++events`.`FirstEntityID` = 1) or 
    (`events`.`Type` = 'Consultation' and `companies++events`.`FirstEntityID` = 1)) and 

    `events`.`StartDate` >= '2015-03-02 00:00:00' AND 
    `events`.`StartDate` <= '2015-03-07 23:59:59'

ORDER BY `events`.`StartDate` ASC
```

Events are linked via `events++persons` to two persons: A doctor and a patient.

This query is enormously slow.

[image]

When I remove the `ORDER BY` (which is essential), the filesort and the temp table vanish. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry for the size of the picture. If you open it in a new tab/window, it will be legible.

Comment: @gvee and ilmari, thanks for the edits.

Comment: No pictures. Just formatted text, thanks.

Comment: And I'm glad I don't have to work with this terrible naming policy

Comment: Do you have a composite index on `companies++event(SecondEntityID,FirstEntityID)` ??

Comment: @Strawberry, what is so terrible about that naming scheme? The DB belongs to an all purpose system, and these kind of table names designate many-to-many connections. Only drawback about that scheme is the ++, which requires escaping. If there's a best practice or a better scheme you could point out to me, I'd be happy to learn!

Comment: Well, maybe 'terrible' was a little strong. I would use an underscore ( _ ) instead of ( ++ ), and 'people' instead of 'persons'.. But more than that, I'd use short aliases, where a one-letter alias indicates a regular table and a two-letter alias indicates a pivot. For clarity, I'd probably stick with 'doctors' and 'patients' as aliases for 'people' - although I wonder if it really makes sense for these to be in the same table. Finally I would get rid of those tiresome backticks!

Comment: Also, I don't understand how this line works because no persons table has been defined !?!?! `LEFT JOIN insurances ON persons.Provider = insurances.ID`. And you join `events++persons` as `events++persons1` but then join doctors back on to `events++persons`!!! I can't help but feel that this naming policy leads to these kinds of errors. Ah, perhaps ep1 is redundant?

Comment: @Strawberry, the backticks are generated by the application in order not to worry about key words, I'll leave them out when posting to StackOverflow. I personally dislike one-letter aliases in examples, especially when many joins are involved. You're right about 'doctors' and 'patients', that is a differentiation that has cristallized over time and not yet been refactored. `persons.Provider` is a foreign key referencing insurances. I've sinced replaced `events++persons` by creating FKs in the `events` table. Sorry my question was so specific, I'll try to do better next time.

Comment: Yes - but there's no persons table in your query. There's `persons as personsPatients` and `persons as personsDoctors`, but no `persons as persons` ?!?!?

Comment: As a side-note: don't fret about the `filesort`. It's just the way explain tells you there is a sort going in. People tend to freak out thinking it indicates a 'sort on disk' kind of operation that is bound to be slow, but it isn't; most likely the filesort operation works 100% in RAM. If you want your results in a certain order, the system has to sort it, period. In some situations there are ways to work around this necessity, but all in all I wouldn't focus too much on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with `companies++events` - all the one-to-one `LEFT JOIN`s in the world don't help when the criterion comes only at the end. I managed to move that info into the main entity (kind of like a pointer) and create a covering index, now the query is lightning-fast.

Comment: I flagged this as 'not an answer' - but actually I guess it is an answer of sorts. Oops.